# Configuring MongoDB driver on PHP

Tags: php, lamp, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed LAMPP on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server and Mongo DB installed. Now I am trying to install MongoDB driver to PHP.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install mongo
```

It is throwing me the below showing error

```
WARNING: "pecl/mongo" is deprecated in favor of "channel:///mongodb" downloading mongo-1.6.14.tgz ...

Starting to download mongo-1.6.14.tgz (210,095 bytes)
.............................................done: 210,095 bytes
118 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
Build with Cyrus SASL (MongoDB Enterprise Authentication) support? [no]: 
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootL9IHAe/mongo-1.6.14
running: /tmp/pear/temp/mongo/configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp    
/bin/php-config --with-mongo-sasl=no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootL9IHAe/mongo-1.6.14':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/mongo/configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp     
/bin/php-config --with-mongo-sasl=no' failed
```

But the same command working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Client. Unable to fix this even after googling a lot.Looking for Solution!

Comment: Looks like it's looking for a working C compiler and failed to find one. Do you have gcc installed?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by installing Autoconf,devssl and gcc compiler. My server is successfully running.

```
sudo apt install gcc
sudo apt-get install autoconf 
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then I have tried to install mongo extension to PHP

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install mongo
```

It was successfully compiled and Installed. Later I have added mongo extension to php.ini

```
echo 'extension=mongo.so' >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

Successfully done.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `sudo pecl install mongodb` and this is working for me. if you php version 5.6 and you check this packages `sudo apt-get install -y autoconf g++ make openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libsasl2-dev libpcre3-dev`